# Is it possible to add custom icons to Bootstrap 4 tabs?

Tags: sass, icons, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to add a custom icon to a Bootstrap 4 tabs? When I try to use the following code, the icon fails to show. What is wrong?

HTML

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-light bg-light" id="leftTabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-leftDefault-tab" data-toggle="tab"
               href="#nav-leftDefault"
               role="tab" aria-controls="tabA1" aria-selected="true"><span class="listicon"></span></li></ul>
```

SCSS:

```
$listico: ("images/icons/list.png");

.listicon{
  background-image: $listico;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `background-image` property correctly with a valid value. In this case you want to use `url()`

```
$listico: url("images/icons/list.png");

.listicon{
  background-image: $listico;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image